# WARNING: Cannot write log file and Permission denied in Ubuntu, when running squid 3

Tags: warnings, ubuntu-14.04, squid

I installed Squid3 on Ubuntu 14.04, and did some minor configuration.
When i run Squid3 using terminal, it shows a warning message as below

```
WARNING: Cannot write log file: /var/log/squid3/cache.log
/var/log/squid3/cache.log: Permission denied
            messages will be sent to 'stderr'.
```

I'm new to squid, so please help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running squid from the terminal, are you doing it as yourself? Check the ownership and permissions of /var/log/squid3/cache.log. You probably do not have the right permissions. Usually services like squid are started automatically as their own user.